# Magento - create a helper class

Tags: magento, helper

I'm having trouble figuring out how to create a helper class with a function in it that's available to *.phtml files.

Can someone describe step by step how I can make the function prtHelloWorld() available to all my *.phtml files?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

it's rather simple and you have to call your helper from template like this:

```
Mage::helper('yourmodule/yourclassfile')->prtHelloWorld();
```

Default helper class is Data and this defaults to Yourmodule/Helper/Data.php

```
Mage::helper('yourmodule')->prtHelloWorld();
```

Comment: You'll need to set your custom extension up of course with a suitable configuration file.  I suggest you read Mr Storm's extensive knowledge base entry to get up to speed http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento

Answer (score 5):

To add to Anton S's, if you want to be able to access the helper's function using $this->prtHelloWorld() in the phtml instead, add it to your Block like this:

public function prtHelloWorld() {
return Mage::helper(whatever)->prtHelloWorld();
}